# Android Studio (version 4.1.0) ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-plugin

Plugins  are installed in android studio but this error shows at "fultter doctor"
Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with many people.. If you installed correctly Flutter and Dart all will works fine in spite of this flutter doctor bug.

Comment: but in android studio shows Flutter and Dart is installed

Comment: Moreover Android studio is also showing error "SDK not found at specified location" when i tried to make a flutter app.

Comment: So you have to select in Preferences > Languages & frameworks > dart > the SDK path

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Comment: i have tired it also, but it gives error -   "ln : The term 'ln' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Note - am using Windows PC

Answer (score 0):

for removing the error "Android Studio (version 4.1.0) ✗ Flutter plugin not installed"
run the command " flutter channel dev && flutter upgrade.

also for removing error "SDK not found at specified location" in android studio, make sure The path to the SDK should be to the main Flutter folder (e.g. C:\src\flutter and not to the bin folder as set in the Environment Variable Path.

Comment: why move to channel dev ? Please give more explanations